# How to write a Python file using VBA?

Tags: python, excel, arcgis, vba

I want to use excel VBA to edit a script file in python then to be run in ArcGis. First I'm open to any easier way but so far I'm having trouble making a multiple line script with my VBA sub!

`& vbCrLf &` doesn't work in the command `Fileout.Write`. When I open my script file everything is on the same line.

neither is `& Char(34) &` working.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim path As String
    path = Application.ActiveWorkbook.path


    Dim Fileout As Object
    Set Fileout = fso.CreateTextFile(path & "\" & "test2.py", True, True)
    Fileout.Write "import arcpy & vbCrLf & lyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer( & Char(34) & limits & Char(34) &) & vbCrLf & lyr.visible = True & vbCrLf & arcpy.RefreshActiveView()'"
    Fileout.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: As written your file contents will be `import arcpy & vbCrLf & lyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer( & Char(34) & limits & Char(34) &) & vbCrLf & lyr.visible = True & vbCrLf & arcpy.RefreshActiveView()'` because you've enclosed all that vba code in double quotes.

Comment: Close your strings with a double quote before the & and re-open them after. Working on answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is here:

```
Fileout.Write "import arcpy & vbCrLf & lyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer( & Char(34) & limits & Char(34) &) & vbCrLf & lyr.visible = True & vbCrLf & arcpy.RefreshActiveView()'"
```

This doesn't give the expected output because you have quotes around the VBA code that you want to be evaluated.  Fixing the quotes gives

```
Fileout.Write "import arcpy" & vbCrLf & "lyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer(" & Char(34) & limits & Char(34) & ")" & vbCrLf & "lyr.visible = True" & vbCrLf & "arcpy.RefreshActiveView()"
```

Let's use some line continuations (`_`) to make this code more legible:

```
Fileout.Write "import arcpy" & vbCrLf _
            & "lyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer(" & Char(34) & limits & Char(34) & ")" & vbCrLf _
            & "lyr.visible = True" & vbCrLf _
            & "arcpy.RefreshActiveView()"
```

`Char(34)` can be accomplished via doubled quotes (`""` inside a quotes evaluates to a double quote):

```
Fileout.Write "import arcpy" & vbCrLf _
            & "lyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer(""" & limits & """)" & vbCrLf _
            & "lyr.visible = True" & vbCrLf _
            & "arcpy.RefreshActiveView()"
```

You can use multiple `WriteLine` in place of the `Write` gets rid of the `& vbCrLf _` on each line:

```
Fileout.WriteLine "import arcpy"
Fileout.WriteLine "lyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer(""" & limits & """)"
Fileout.WriteLine "lyr.visible = True"
Fileout.WriteLine "arcpy.RefreshActiveView()"
```

Comment: Thanx I like the WriteLine approach!

Answer (score 0):

Here goes: you were on the right track but just stumbled when dealing with the string building.

You want to concatenate bits of strings surrounded by double quotes, using the & operator. When you need double quotes within a string, just double them up.

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim path As String
    path = Application.ActiveWorkbook.path


    Dim Fileout As Object
    Set Fileout = fso.CreateTextFile(path & "\" & "test2.py", True, True)
    Fileout.Write "import arcpy" & vbCrLf & "lyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer(""limits"")" & vbCrLf & "lyr.visible = True" & vbCrLf & "arcpy.RefreshActiveView()'"
    Fileout.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: giving a solution is fine, explaining the problem before is way better...